# Loop through object, and return the sum of each value with similar properties

Tags: javascript

this might be a simple fix... but with the code below, I'm getting `{a:2}`, when it should just be 1.

```
const object = {a:1, b:2, b:2};

let sum = {};

for(let property in object){
  sum[property] = object[property] + object[property];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Not sure what the issue is.. Also, I'm trying to understand how the properties are passed into the sum object. Because from my understanding `sum[property]` returns a value, not a property; and so does `object[property]`. So how do `a:` and `b:` properties get passed into `sum`? Trying to get a visualization of how this works.

Thank you

Comment: const object = {a:1, b:2, b:2};
this object itself is wrong... you can't have duplicate keys

Comment: 1. object can't have 2 b values.  as you have it, object = { a:1, b: 2 }
2. you're setting sum[property] = 2 * object[property]

what you really want is reduce
sum = Object.keys(object).reduce((accumulator, key) => accumulator + object[key])

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

This line:

```
sum[property] = object[property] + object[property];
```

will sum two `a` properties

```
sum["a"] = object["a"] + object["a"]
```

That causes `sum["a"] === 2`

**Second:**

Object can not have the same properties.

**Alternative:**

You can use array of objects, like this:

```
const arr = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {b: 2}];
```

And fix the code to return the sum of each value with similar properties

```
const arr = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {b:2}, {a: 8, b: 5}];

let sum = {};

arr.forEach(object => {
  for(let property in object) {
   if (sum[property] === undefined) sum[property] = object[property];
   else sum[property] += object[property];
 }
})

console.log(sum); // { a: 9, b: 9}
```

Comment: Hey thank you, this is a wonderful explanation. I do have a follow up question. How do the properties get applied to sum? It's initially an empty object, and from the else if statements, they seem to be passing the values rather than the properties. Hope that makes sense... Basically how does sum['a'] translate to {a:}. Thanks again

Comment: Actually, `sum["a"]` is same as `sum.a`, both of them reference to the value of the `a` property of the `sum`. At first, there is no `a` property in the `sum`, so if we do `sum["a"]` or `sum.a`, it will return `undefined`, and because it's `undefined`, we need to assign a value to it to make it "defined", so we get the value of the `a` property of the `object` and assign it to the `a` property of the `sum`: `sum[a] = object[a];`. The `sum` now has `a` property.

Comment: Read this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for the clarification. I forgot that the dot notation and using brackets is the same as adding or accessing an object's property. Thank you, and also for the url!

Answer (score 0):

```
const object = {a:1, b:2, b:2};
console.log(object) //{a:1, b:2}
```

There can only be one unique key